Semantic-UI dropdown select props key vs value purpose and usage
In Semantic UI (especially in React) the wide pattern is to pass tree fields per element:
{
key:'1',
value:'1',
text: "first item"}
}

In all examples I see key==value. What is the purpose of having two different fields, which basically seem to have the same function. And what would be the recommended approach usage.
I couldn't find any meaningful documentation. (this thread has contradictory statements : https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI-React/issues/1710 )
what would happen if i have duplicated values?
[
{
key:'1',
value:'A',
text: "first item"}
},
{
key:'2',
value:'A',
text: "first item"}
},
]

